# Empty datapoints received while retrieving AWS S3 Request metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Following is my payload

```
response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/S3',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'BucketName',
            'Value': 'foo-bar'
        },
        {
            'Name': 'StorageType',
            'Value': 'AllStorageTypes'
        }
    ],
    MetricName='BytesUploaded',
    StartTime=datetime(2021, 3, 11),
    EndTime=datetime(2021, 3, 14),
    Period=86400,
    Statistics=[
        'Maximum', 'Average'
    ]
)
```

and this is the response

```
{'Label': 'BytesUploaded', 'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '1c6b02e9-9a8f-48e9-a2fd-1e21fd31a096', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '1c6b02e9-9a8f-48e9-a2fd-1e21fd31a096', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '336', 'date': 'Tue, 16 Mar 2021 05:51:05 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

From AWS Console, I'm able to see datapoints for the same timestamp.  I tried increasing the timeframe but it still gibes the same result

Can some help me please?  thanks[image]

Comment: Got it..! I used the AWS CLI command provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645974/412129

Answer (score 0):

First, If period variable is a refresh period maybe you should need to reduce. When I checked out to example, I saw period is 300.

Second, try to change endTime like:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

EndTime = datetime.utcnow(),
```

Comment: Thanks @Yunus  I have tried those options earlier as well.  It didn't help.  I'm even wondering if there is a different method to use than get_metric_statistics()