# boto3 - "errorMessage": "copy_object() only accepts keyword arguments."

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

```
CopySource = {
'Bucket': file.bucket_name, 
'Key': file.key
}
Bucket = project_bucket
Key = file.key
s3_client.copy_object(Bucket,Key,CopySource)
```

trying to copy object from one directory of s3 bucket to another s3 with same directory structure

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634845/python-boto3-get-metric-statistics-only-accepts-keyword-arguments

Comment: I see you posted new question which includes code from my answer. Thus accepting of this answer would be appreciated, as clearly it helped you pass to the next problem.

Comment: I got new error.   "errorMessage": "expected string or bytes-like object",

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object), it should be:

```
s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=project_bucket,Key=file.key,CopySource)
```

Comment: I tried all possible combinations.  I am using python 3.9

Comment: @milindpotdar My answer addresses the error you reported. Your python code that you posted is invalid in any python version. If you have different error message, then new question should be made with your python code.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.